# android : limit on the total number of sounds played?

Tags: android, audio, limit, playback

My app plays a selected number of short sounds (stored in res/raw). The sounds are randomly selected in the array soundfileFR[] containing these sounds.
The selected number of sounds is played on the click of a button, one sounds after another using the "for" loop.
The app runs perfectly fine... except that, for some unkown reason, it will never play more than 30 of these sounds in a row, i.e. if I start the app and select "35" as the number of sounds to be played, it will not play the last five sounds. Alternatively, if I first select "20" it plays all the sounds, then I select "12" and it does not play the last 2 sounds.

Each sound is a ".wav" weighing about 50 Ko only.
Is there some kind of memory limit ?
Do I need "reset" the mediaplayer (?) between each sounds ?  If so how ?

The "for" loop is below :

```
for (int n = 1; n <= totalNb; n++) {
    final int randomNb;

    final int nn = n;

    randomNb = (int)(Math.floor(Math.random()*(10))); // random nb between 0 and 9                              

    handlerH.postDelayed(new Runnable(){

        public void run() {

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), soundfileFR[randomNb]);  // initializes a sound for folder res/raw

            mp.seekTo(0); 
            mp.start();  // plays the sound

            pgbSpoken.setProgress(nn);  // incrementation of the progressBar

        }

    },
    initialdelay + n * intervalrep);    


} // end of "for"
```

Thank you for your help.

Pierre